# Bootstrap popover links not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a page that involves a share button that, when clicked, pops up a twitter bootstrap popover and inside it are the share links.

```
var content = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u='+link+'">Post to facebook</a><br>';
  content += '<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status='+link+'">Post to twitter</a><br>';
  $('.sharelist').popover({
      'title': 'Share this Playlist', 
      'placement': 'bottom', 
      'html': true, 
      'content': content
  });
```

And it does almost that. The thing pops up, the links are there and blue, hovering over them changes the cursor to a little hand, but when I click, nothing happens! I can right click to open in a new tab, and the links work again.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You should use `encodeURIComponent(link)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Jack, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code. Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

```
ADD A CLASS TO YOUR LINK NAMED "post-popover"  and
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.post-popover').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    title: 'Share this Playlist',
    content: 'content',
    html: true, 
    trigger: 'click'
  });
```

});

Comment: vr1911428 This didn't work. I don't know how it was supposed to work, I tried pasting it in, nothing changed.